# Get JSON objects from MYSQL to an Array

Tags: android, mysql, database, arrays, json

How could i get more `JSON object` from the `php page` which gets information from `MYSQL` database with the same keyword "`example`" and  to insert all the values from that column (`"example"` column) in an Array, Like:

`exemple_array[1] = (first value of column example ) from the Mysql database`.

Could anyone help me or give me some tutorials or useful tips ?

Answer (score 1):

For one, it doesn't matter that it's from MySql database, only that the server is returning a JSON structure to you.

Android ships with JSON parsing classes that are very easy to work with: JSONObject and JSONArray.  If you know in advance what the format is going to be, you can easily use them with a string of JSON data you receive from a remote server (provided you have the HTTP stuff worked out already)

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: could anyone help me with this ?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537511/json-mysql-get-two-integers-and-a-string/10551010#10551010